# regular expression for start and end of username

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to make regular expression that:

- should be at least *6 alphanumeric characters* and combine it with *symbols*
- only *symbols* allowed are `.`(*dot*), `-`(*dash*) or `_`(*underscore*).
- **Must not begin with any *symbols*.**
- **Must not end with any *symbols*.**
- **Must not include consecutive *symbols*.**

This regex is for first two items on the list `^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{6,}$`

How can I exclude those symbols on *start* and the *end* of string?

Comment: Shouldn't the `a-zA-Z0-9` part be put aside? Because you need at least 6 of them, excluding symbols

Comment: It should be at least 6 alphanumeric characters or at least 6 in total (including symbols)?

Comment: What is a "symbol"? There are many symbols in ASCII/Unicode. Which do you not want to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @Kratnik's answer, to express that the string does not start or end with special characters we can explicitly use the other alternatives. Hence a simpler version:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*[._-]{2})[\w.-]{4,}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

1. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - alphanumeric at start and end
2. `(?!.*[._-]{2})` a guarantee that no two special characters follow consequently
3. `[\w.-]{4,}` - 4 or more of the possible characters in the middle

Comment: `\w` also includes underscore. OP may consider this a "symbol".

Comment: Very interesting solution. It works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

see if this helps

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{4,}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Comment: This does not meet the second rule **Must not include consecutive symbols**

Comment: This is uncorrect expression. But there are no matches when I type  "some-text" . I changed places between  . - _  for . _ - and it works. Also it includes consecutive symbols